# How to @extend without class name in sass?

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way to extend class if parent has no class name in sass?

***scss***

```
div {

  &:last-child {
    margin: 1rem;

    div {
      @extend from parent here i.e. &:last-child
    }
  }
}
```

`@extend &:last-child` does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the element?

Comment: @Nitheesh basically I want to override `margin` which is applied to `&:last-child` from children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(To answer my own question), You can use the `@at-root` directive to move `child` selector to the root level so that it can extend the `parent` selector.

***scss***

```
div {

  &:last-child {
    margin: 1rem;

    div {
      @at-root div:last-child {
        @extend div:last-child;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***css*** output

```
div:last-child {
  margin: 1rem;
}

div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```